# Sql Server 2008 R2 Database backup and restore functionality by C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, backup

I develop a windows application for a small shop for generating invoices.
Now I want to give a functionality for the user to make backup of each day database on a button click from the windows application. Also he should be able to restore the database from these backup.

Please help me i searched many topics but not works.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` name space and use the `BackUp` Method provided. It has various backup options.
Please  [See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx)

Comment: it helps a lot but not fully solve my problem yet..Please give me a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public void BackupDatabase(string BackUpLocation, string BackUpFileName, string      DatabaseName, string ServerName)
{
    DatabaseName = "[" + DatabaseName + "]";

    string fileUNQ = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() +"_"+ DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()+ DateTime.Now .Minute .ToString () + "_" + DateTime .Now .Second .ToString () ;

    BackUpFileName = BackUpFileName + fileUNQ + ".bak";
    string SQLBackUp = @"BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = '" + BackUpLocation + @"\" + BackUpFileName + @"'";

    string svr = "Server=" + ServerName + ";Database=" + DatabaseName + ";Integrated Security=True";

    SqlConnection cnBk = new SqlConnection(svr);
    SqlCommand cmdBkUp = new SqlCommand(SQLBackUp, cnBk);

    try
    {
        cnBk.Open();
        cmdBkUp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //MessageBox.Show("Done");
        MessageBox.Show(SQLBackUp + " ######## Server name " + ServerName + " Database " + DatabaseName + " successfully backed up to " + BackUpLocation + @"\" + BackUpFileName + "\n\nBackUp Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //MessageBox.Show(SQLBackUp + " ######## Server name " + ServerName + " Database " + DatabaseName + " successfully backed up to " + BackUpLocation + @"\" + BackUpFileName + "\n Back Up Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    finally
    {
        if (cnBk.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnBk .Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```